# Made changes to desktop.ini with batch file but folder icons won't change

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, cmd, desktop.ini

I used a batch file to make changes to a desktop.ini file by replacing the existing one with a new one. The code for this part is:

```
move /y "Games\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%\Games"
```

It manages to successfully replace the file (I used attrib +s and +h) but the folder's icon doesn't change. What can I do to make Windows Explorer recognize the change? I heard something about SHChangeNotify before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was so simple. All I had to do was this:

```
attrib +s +r "%UserProfile%\Games"
```

Icon changed instantly.

Comment: pure goo! finally!! i very nice wend the job if do by a simple action!!